# Correct way of labeling text (not form element) for accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm creating a content heavy page that is broken up into several small chunks of content. I want this content to be structured in a way that is accessibility friendly.

I originally planned on using the `label` tag for each piece of content but from what I understand, they are for form elements only. I'm using a series of header (`h2`, `h3`, `h4`...) tags for the main structure of the content but I'm a bit confused as to what I should use for the frequent chunks of short content that needs to be labeled i.e.: Work phone, Home phone, Membership type.

**What element should I use to label one-liner pieces of content?**

My main concern is how screen readers will digest the content.

*I'm laughing to myself at how much effort I'm putting into something as simple as HTML.*

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Comment: Why don't you use `id/classes` to organize content?

Comment: That won't help screen readers digest the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often natural language already conveys what you want to say, without needing any special element:

```html
My work phone: <a href="tel:+1-000">000</a>
```

For other cases (or if you want to make cases like the above one explicit), especially if you have a set of name-value groups, and you don’t want to phrase natural sentences, you could use the [`dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element):

```
<dl>
  <dt>Work</dt> <dd><a href="tel:+1-000">000</a></dd>
  <dt>Home</dt> <dd><a href="tel:+1-111">111</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: It seems like the dl element is the route i'll need to go.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer to your question is: use **microdata**.

However, "microdata" has evolved quite a lot over the 10 years - various markup standards have emerged - earlier microformats like `hCard`, `hCalendar` & `hRecipe` and later, more sophisticated initiatives like `RDFa`, `schema.org`, `JSON-LD` - and all have continued to grow and change.

The answer below addresses **2 specific considerations**:

1. How to make telephone numbers immediately apparent to user-agents like browsers and screen-readers.
2. How to (begin to) establish semantic differentiation between different telephone numbers on the same web-page.

**1. Adding Interactivity to Telephone Numbers in mark-up**

To assist screenreaders, you can mark up telephone numbers in `HTML5`, using a syntax similar to the `mailto:` email address syntax:

**Email:** `<a href="mailto:me@example.com">me@example.com</a`>

**Tel:** `<a href="tel:+14295663674">429-566-3674</a>`

N.B. The number stated in the `tel:` link must begin with a `+`, immediately followed by the international dialling code.

The `HTML` above will also add interactivity to your marked-up telephone number.

***eg.*** It will enable smartphones to start calling the number when you click on it in a mobile browser. It will also enable (some) permitted VOIP programmes to start calling the number, when you click on it in a desktop or laptop browser.

## =====

**2. Distinguishing Home Phone numbers and Work Phone numbers in mark-up**

The `HTML` above will not explicitly distinguish between Work Phone numbers and Home Phone Numbers.

You can start to build such a distinction by employing a *microdata* vocabulary like that found at http://schema.org/:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Alice</h2>

    <dl itemprop="contactPoint" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPoint/">
        <dt itemprop="contactType">Home:</dt>
        <dd itemprop="telephone"><a href="tel:+14296774785">429-677-4785</a></dd>

        <dt itemprop="contactType">Work:</dt>
        <dd itemprop="telephone"><a href="tel:+14295663674">429-566-3674</a></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: @unor's response specifically mentioned the DL element which I agree with for my specific situation. I wish I could accept both answers :(

Comment: I also used the definition list (`<dl>`) in my answer above. (4 hours earlier).